# Installed wrong graphics driver, says Shader Model not supported, use OpenGL

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, opengl

After I installed the wrong graphics driver, things are laggy/freezy, and any games I open give me this error:

> Video card error. Your graphics card does not seem support Shader Model 1.1+. Would you like to swap to OpenGl mode? If this is your first time running [game], your likely need to click 'Yes' here.

I had this issue with another graphics driver where whenever I play a game, the screen freezes/lags for a second every 3 seconds, I fixed that by updating my driver with the help of my friend who sent me a link to the download of the updater.

For this graphics card, I tried to install the same driver my friend sent me and now I can't view any video files on my computer, or open a game.

When I swap to OpenGL, the game is laggy, way more laggy, and colors are different.

Comment: find and install the right driver?